# How can I recognise Non printable unicode characters in python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to generate a Unicode string using random characters. I don't want to have non-printtable characters in a string.
using 'unichr(codepoint)' function I am converting codepoint to Unicode and using 'unicode.encode('utf-8')' I am converting Unicode to string. 
I tried using string.printable but that covers only ASCII.

Comment: Just an idea but what about using exception handling? Would that be considered a bad practice?

Comment: What do you consider to be a non-printable character? In which font?

Comment: >>> u=unichr(12352) 
 >>> print u
   o/p for above code prints  ぀
 >>> u=unichr(12353)
 >>> print u
    o/p for above code prints ぁ
First one is the non printable character. The second one is.

Comment: This is a far more complicated issue than most people think, because with the interpretation of ANSI color and control code sequences, you will have a string of printable characters that will not actually be seen in your terminal, except as color, font or format changes. This also depend on your `LOCALE` settings among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unicodedata.html) library.

```
import unicodedata

def strip_string(self, string):
  """Cleans a string based on a whitelist of printable unicode categories
  You can find a full list of categories here:
  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm
  """
  letters     = ('LC', 'Ll', 'Lm', 'Lo', 'Lt', 'Lu')
  numbers     = ('Nd', 'Nl', 'No')
  marks       = ('Mc', 'Me', 'Mn')
  punctuation = ('Pc', 'Pd', 'Pe', 'Pf', 'Pi', 'Po', 'Ps')
  symbol      = ('Sc', 'Sk', 'Sm', 'So')
  space       = ('Zs',)

  allowed_categories = letters + numbers + marks + punctuation + symbol + space

  return u''.join([ c for c in string if unicodedata.category(c) in allowed_categories ])
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/Jonty/6705090

Comment: Why don't you consider `؁ ` (`U+0601`) to be "printable"?

Comment: Even if potentially printable, there is still the problem of font support.  Most fonts don't support all printable Unicode characters.

Comment: @一二三 It is just a guess on what the user would consider printable. If you want to consider U+0601 printable, add `'Cf'` to the list.

Comment: @MarkTolonen To check for font-support, you will need something like [pyfontaine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fontaine)

Comment: No doubt this is a good effort. But this is not a complete solution.  I mean in Ll or Lm group there are still few characters which are non-printable.